# Printing the results of a gene search to a HTML tab

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have created a managed bean that searches a gene database currently it only returns the result to the glass fish console. I am wondering if anyone can offer any suggestions on how to get my search results to display into my gene/protein search tab.

My current set of code:

MainPage.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <!-- this allows the page to see the welcomepage style sheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Group1/welcomepage.css"   media="screen"/>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <!-- allows the page to see the jquery function see "http://jquery.com/" for description -->
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- allows the page to see the js script tabs see file for detailed comments-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "tabs.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- the wrapper places everyting in one frame so the objects do not move when  browser size is altered-->     
       <div id ="wrapper">  
        <div id = "main">
            <div id ="header">

                    <!-- again the logo this one will appear in the header in the top left and when clicked returns you to the home page -->
                <a href="index.xhtml">
                    <img  id ="logo1"  alt="Group1 logo"/>
                </a>

                <!-- this is the single search bar and button the "this.select()" function selects all the content in the search box in one click-->

                <form name="Search" onsubmit="#{SearchUniprot.query}"> 
                    <input type="text" id ="GeneralSearch" name="Search" value="#{SearchUniprot.userSearch}" onclick="this.select();"/>
                    <input type="submit" id ="subSearch" value="Search" name="GenSearchButton"/>
                </form>    
              </div>   

        <!-- tab container this created the tabs according the to style set out in the CSS -->
        <div id="tab-container">  
            <ul class="tab-menu">  
                <li id="Start" class="active">Start</li>  
                <li id="Genes">Genes/Proteins</li>  
                <li id="Litrature">Litrature</li>  
                <li id="Analysis">Analysis</li>
            </ul>  
        <div class="clear"></div> 

        <!-- each div section below determines what is written in each tab -->  
        <div class="tab-top-border"></div>
            <div id="Start-tab" class="tab-content active">
                <h1>Recent Activiy</h1>
                <p>Recent files will be shown here</p>  
            </div>

            <div id="Genes-tab" class="tab-content">
                <h1>Genes and Proteins</h1>
                <p>Results for genes and proteins based on search </p>
            </div>

            <div id="Litrature-tab" class="tab-content">  
                <h1>Litrature</h1>
                <p>Results of Litrature search will be shown here</p>
            </div>

            <div id="Analysis-tab" class="tab-content">  
                <h1>Analysis</h1>
                <p>A type of analysis will be shown here</p>
            </div>

            </div>

            </div>
          </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

SearchUniProt.java

```
package TestGeneSearch;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean (name ="SearchUniprot" )
@RequestScoped
public class SearchUniprot {

   String userSearch;         

    public String getUserSearch() {
        return userSearch;
    }

    public void setUserSearch(String userSearch) {
        this.userSearch = userSearch;
    }

    public SearchUni getQuery() {

        // make a new object of the SearchUniProt class and set the search term - obviously we need to read this in from the user in a demo
        SearchUni query = new SearchUni("tuna");
        //run the RunQuery method in SearchUniprot
        query.RunQuery();

        return query;
    }


    public SearchUniprot() {

    }


}
```

SearchUni.java

```
package TestGeneSearch;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import uk.ac.ebi.webservices.axis1.stubs.ebeye.EBISearchService_PortType;
import uk.ac.ebi.webservices.axis1.stubs.ebeye.EBISearchService_Service;
import uk.ac.ebi.webservices.axis1.stubs.ebeye.EBISearchService_ServiceLocator;

@Stateful

public class SearchUni {

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

        //searchterm = what you want to search for
        private String searchterm;

    public SearchUni() {
    }


//constrcutor
    public SearchUni(String s) {
        searchterm = s;
    }

    public String[] RunQuery() {
        try {

            //set up to connect to the searchservice
            EBISearchService_Service service = new EBISearchService_ServiceLocator();
            EBISearchService_PortType srvProxy = service.getEBISearchServiceHttpPort();
            // Get the number of results for the query - we don;t necessarily need this but it may be useful
            int result = srvProxy.getNumberOfResults("uniprot", searchterm);
            System.out.println(result);

            //get all results IDs - can easily limit it to however many we want
            String[] ids = srvProxy.getAllResultsIds("uniprot", searchterm);
            for (int i = 0; i + 1 < ids.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(ids[i]);
            }

            //get more fields - the fields we can get depend on the database to be searched. 
            //a note about protein names in Uniprot - Uniprot contains two sections, reviewed and unreviewd
            //the reviewed entries will have a Reccomended Name (descRecName), the unreviewed entries will have
            //a Submitted name (descSubName)  - so each of our results will have either a descRecName or a descSubName
            //but not both.
            //gene name (gene_primary_name) may be null
            //accession number (acc) is a stable identifier - the id field printed out above is not the same as an
            //accession number and shouldn't be assumed to be stable

            String fields[] = {"acc", "descRecName", "descSubName", "gene_primary_name", "organism_scientific_name"};
            String[][] results = srvProxy.getResults("uniprot", searchterm, fields, 1, 100);
            for (int i = 0; i < result; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(results[i][j]);
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
       return null;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the result in the bean and show the value of the bean in the file - read about how to display bean values in XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You're only seeing the results in the console because you're just printing the results in this line

```
System.out.println(ids[i]);
```

What you need to do is to store this results somewhere, make them available to your managed bean (for example, storing in a managed bean attribute) and make this information available in your xhtml via this attribute getters and setters.

One thing that is not clear to me yet is why do you need a stateful EJB for this task. If the only thing you need is to query the database and show the results, you may prefer to use a stateless EJB instead, which is simpler and probably will perform better too.

I also suggest you to use some JSF frontend library such as primefaces, so you'll have a whole set of rich GUI elements ready to use. In your specific case, since you're dealing with genomic data, some results (I guess) can be quite big and you may want to use some lazy loading features that are trivial to do with primefaces (and not so trivial to do without it)

The logic is like this

xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:inputText id="criteria" value="#{myMB.criteria}"/>
        <p:inputText id="result" value="#{myMB.result}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="query" action="#{myMB.query}" update="result"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

when you hit the query button, myMB.query() method will be called, with the myMB.criteria populated in your managed bean, that may look like this

```
package mypackage;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyMB implements Serializable{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    private String criteria;
    private String result;

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEJB;

    public void query(){
        this.result = myEJB.query(this.criteria);
    }

    public String getCriteria() {
        return criteria;
    }

    public void setCriteria(String criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }


}
```

notice that I use here a stateless EJB like this

```
package mypackage;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

    public String query(String criteria) {
        //do your query here
        return "xyz";
    }

}
```

after the query is done, the result will go to myMB.result, but it will only be shown after the xhtml process the

```
update="result"
```

notice that "result" in the line above is not myMB.result, but the xhtml tag with id="result"

I hope it's clearer now.